# Why can LINQ not translate string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()?

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone explain why this compiles but creates an exception at runtime because it is not able to translate to sql/entities correctly?  Trying to gain understanding of what is happening behind the scenes.

```
 var data = (from e in db.Employees
            join egp in db.EmployeeGrievanceMappings on e.EmployeeID equals egp.EmployeeID
            join et in db.EmployeeTypes on egp.EmployeeTypeID equals et.EmployeeTypeID
                    where et.EmployeeTypeName == employeeeType
            select new GrievantStewardBO()
            {
                Id = e.EmployeeADID,
                EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
                EmployeeTypeID = egp.EmployeeTypeID,
                GrievanceID = egp.GrievanceID,
                EmployeeGrievanceID = egp.EmployeeGrievanceID,
                text =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( e.EmployeeLastName) ? e.EmployeeFirstName : e.EmployeeLastName + "," + e.EmployeeFirstName,
                FirstName = e.EmployeeFirstName,
                LastName = e.EmployeeLastName

            }).
        ToList();
```

I know I can write this and have it work correctly, I just wanted to gain some understanding for similar run-ins with LINQ.

```
text =   e.EmployeeLastName == null || e.EmployeeLastName.Trim() == "" ? e.EmployeeFirstName : e.EmployeeLastName + "," + e.EmployeeFirstName
```

Related question:  Why does Trim() translate correctly in LINQ?

Comment: Linq to objects can handle it but the expression cannot be translated into Sql by Linq-to-sql. Here is a complete list of unsupported string methods for linq to sql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because no one has programmed the entity provider to translate that expression to SQL.  Features are not free.  You can see which string functions are supported [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

Comment: is this linq to sql or entity framework or something else?

Comment: It is *some* Linq provider.  Which one it is doesn't really matter; whatever Linq provider is being used doesn't support this particular method.

Comment: If you don't need lazy loading your can solve the problem by calling `ToList()` on your result first, which will take the data out of your Linq provider and put it into Linq to Objects (i.e. an `IEnumerable`).

Comment: If you are using C# 6 and the latest version of Enity Framework you might be able to do `string.IsNullOrEmpty( e.EmployeeLastName?.Trim())`, Have not tested it, so it might not work. I know `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is supported by entity framework, but I don't know if the `?.` operator is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using "Linq to Entites", likely either Entity Framework or Linq2Sql. When using Linq to Entites your linq statement is turned in to a expression, parsed, then is converted in to a SQL query. The problem you are having is as simple as the person who wrote the "parse" step did not support `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in the parser so it does not know how to turn that function in to a SQL string.

You must either use the long form like you showed or update to a newer version of your library that supports it. It appears that the version on GitHub of [Entity Framework 6 does `IsNullOrEmpty`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/527ae18fe23f7649712e9461de0c90ed67c3dca9/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ELinq/MethodCallTranslator.cs#L1408-L1439), perhaps you could create a new method of IsNullOrWhitespace and do a request to get it merged in.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ you have there is an [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) which gets translated into SQL. Somebody has to evaluate the expression and create the resulting SQL. This process does not know what to do with `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, hence it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Nobody wrote code to handle this specific method in the LINQ provider you are using. Method calls are not translated to SQL (or whatever the provider translates to) by some procedure. Method calls are handled on a case by case basis and the common methods are hardcoded into the provider. If nobody wrote code to handle this method the method does not work.

On another note why didn't they handle this specific method? Probably they were either reusing code from LINQ to SQL for their generation code or they wanted to work with .NET framework 3.5 and this method was added in 4.0